# How to make an ant design modal for angular (ng zorro v.7) draggable?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I use Ant Design of Angular and I need to make modal window draggable. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [issue](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/4549) under discussion. Actually, it's a most-wanted feature of ng-zorro-antd. LOL.

For now, you can use template modal (instead of creating via `NzModalService`) and attach a [`cdkDrag`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) on it.

Comment: @hersir1 we'll support when this PR merged https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/pull/4978